# html() and val() usage in chrome versus IE

Tags: jquery

I have the following code fragment which is looping through a dictionary returned from a web method, and appending some values to a textarea. It works without issue from IE:

```
$.each(results, function (key, value) {                           
  if ($('#TextArea1').val() == '') {
    $('#TextArea1').html(key + '&#10;');                      
  } else {                                      
    $('#TextArea1').html($('#TextArea1').val() + key + '&#10;');
  }
});
```

This appends on a new line just fine in IE, however in chrome it doesn't append anything. Is the the `&#10;` character for a newline in a textarea not supported in chrome?

TIA!!!!!!

Comment: `\n` is for new line. Or even `\r\n`.

Comment: Firstly, your code works fine in Chrome. Secondly, you should also be using `val()` to set the value of a `textarea`, not `html()`.

Comment: you are correct. thank you.